# Error 404 page not working after setting it up on cPanel

Tags: html, cpanel, web-hosting

So my page **[zemenu.tech](https://zemenu.tech)** recently moved from infinity free to cPanel for hosting, and my team and I keep getting the unsecured thing on top even though the SSL is valid and on further notice it was the error page not redirecting to the one I created using cPanel but to infinity free's 404 page and that was the one causing problems. I deleted the infinity free from the name server and also created a 404.shtml page on cPanel, but it is still getting redirected to their 404 site, how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, fixed it, cPanel hides .htaccess files when using the default file manager so used a 3rd party ftp app(FileZilla) and deleted the .htaccess file that Infinity Free generates by default for every website it hosts